# Birational map and birational morphism in algebraic geometry

Tags: algebraic-geometry, notation

In algebraic geometry do the two terms "**birational map**" and "**birational morphism**" indicate the same object?

By reading wikipedia the answer seems to be NO:

- A birational map from $X$ to $Y$ is a rational map $f: X \rightarrow Y$ such that there is a rational map $Y\rightarrow X$ inverse to $f$.
- A birational morphism $f: X → Y$, is a morphism which is birational. That is, $f$ is defined everywhere, but its inverse may not be.

The above distinction is also true for example in the book "Beaville - Complex algebraic surfaces"? The author doesn't give the basic definitions.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are correct: they are not the same.  In general, when people say "morphism", they mean an honest, defined-everywhere morphism.  A "map" usually just means a rational map, defined on an open subset.

For a basic surface example, let $X$ be $\mathbb P^2$ blown up at the point $[1,0,0]$.  There is a blow-down $\pi : X \to \mathbb P^2$: this is a birational morphism (defined everywhere).  There is also an inverse map $\mathbb P^2 \dashrightarrow X$, defined everywhere except $[1,0,0]$.  This is a birational map, but isn't a morphism.

Answer (score 2):

Consider the hyperbola $H=\{(a,b)\in K^2 : ab=1\}$ and the projection $p:H\rightarrow K$ to the first coordinate. Then $p$ is an injective morphism with the rational map $q:K\rightarrow H$, $a\mapsto (a,a^{-1})$ as an inverse. However $q$ is only defined on the open set $K\setminus 0$. ($K$ is an (algebraically closed) field.)